# div height: percent minus px

Tags: css

I'm very new to web-design, so this might be a stupid question, but bear with me please.

I want to create a `div` that is centred horizontally and has a height that always extends to 175px from the bottom- so basically a height of 100% minus 175px.

The content in that `div` is longer than the height and should be scrollable

Here is what I've got:

```
.container {
    width: 600px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}
```

But now I need some kind of cut off line that will stop the content to extend to the bottom of the page.

Comment: It really sounds like you just want a 175 pixel high footer that is always stuck to the window's (viewport) bottom edge regardless of the amount of content above.

Comment: yes, i guess that might solve the problem but the footer would need to be transparent... how could i create such a footer?

Comment: Look into `position: fixed;`  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help to know what kind of visual effect you're trying to achieve as well. Very often in CSS the visual effect is not totally symmetric with the code that you're using-- in other words, very often code is used to create "illusions"... anyway I digress.

for reference see http://jsfiddle.net/xqBph/6/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
      some content
    </div>
</div>

body,
html {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative
}

#container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: -175px;
    outline: 1px solid red; 
}

#content {padding-top: 175px}
```